# difference between coverlet.collector and coverlet.msbuild?

Tags: .net

based on https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/tree/master

`coverlet.collector` is related to "VSTest Integration" and `coverlet.msbuild` is related to "MSBuild Integration".

I am confused with `coverlet.collector`, doesn't it need MSBUild as well, because you have to build your projects before running tests?

and what does "VSTest Integration" mean? isn't that VS just an IDE? how can a data collector related to an IDE?